# How do I merge non-generic IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

I'm trying to have one object inherit from another object where properties of type `IEnumerable` will be merged together.

Both objects are of same class.

```
foreach (var property in typeof(Placeholder).GetProperties())
{
    var childProperty = property.GetValue(childPlaceholder);
    var parentProperty = property.GetValue(parentPlaceholder);

    IEnumerable childIEnumerable = childProperty as IEnumerable;
    IEnumerable parentIEnumberable = parentProperty as IEnumerable;

    // How do I merge childIEnumerable with parentIEnumberable into one IEnumerable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the LINQ [`Cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-6.0) method that allows you to turn a non-generic Enumerable to a generic one. Assuming that you know the `Parent` and `Child` types (where `Child : Parent`):

```cs
foreach (var property in typeof(Placeholder).GetProperties())
{
    var childProperty = property.GetValue(childPlaceholder);
    var parentProperty = property.GetValue(parentPlaceholder);
    IEnumerable childIEnumerable = childProperty as IEnumerable;
    IEnumerable parentIEnumerable = parentProperty as IEnumerable;
    IEnumerable<Parent> mergedEnumerable = childIEnumerable
        .Cast<Child>()
        .Concat(parentIEnumerable.Cast<Parent>());
}
```

If you don't know the specific types, you can also cast them to `object`:

```cs
IEnumerable<object> merged = childIEnumerable
    .Cast<object>()
    .Concat(parentIEnumerable.Cast<object>());
```

Comment: The enumerable types in the class have different property so I don't know if there's a away to figure out the type during runtime. Also, I tried casting them to object but when I do property.SetValue(childPlaceholder, merged) it throws an error because the generic type of merged does not match the actual type of property

Comment: @JasonLiu Well, you did not tell us that you're trying to write anything back. In that case, you need to know what the actual type of the property is. This is starting to look like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve with this code? What's the `Placeholder` type?